# Image Processing Terminology Question: Even/Odd Quadrature Pairs and Center Surround Filter

Tags: filters

I am reading the paper *Learning to Detect Natural Image Boundaries
Using Local Brightness, Color, and Texture Cues* available [here](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/papers/mfm-pami-boundary.pdf).

In section 2.2.2, page 5, slightly after halfway done the page on the left the authors use the terms

- even and odd quadrature pairs of filters
- a center-surround filter

For instance an example of an even/odd quadrature filter they discuss is a Gaussian second derivative filter (even) and its Hilbert Transform (odd).

The example of a second surround filter is a Difference of Gaussians filter.

Any elaboration on what these two terms mean in general much appreciated.